# s3 policy allow multiple IPs at the same statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip-address, private, access-denied

I am trying to allow connection to a bucket from 3 specified ip addresses. When I add them this way:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "ip1",
                    "aws:SourceIp": "ip2",
                    "aws:SourceIp": "ip3"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Upon saving only one line of the three will be kept and so I can only have one IP set. Any idea how can I do it without going to long adding new statements and workarounds?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "testPolicy",
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/subfolder/subfolder2/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32",
                        "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

You've to provide IP's in the form of subnet like
wrong: 1.2.3.4
Right: 1.2.3.4/32

Answer (score 0):

It isn't mandatory to apply the routing prefix for the specific IP address. According to the [official AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_IPAddress),

> If you specify an IP address without the associated routing prefix, IAM uses the default prefix value of /32.

I've tested it at my end and it works even after not specifying /32 after the IP address.